# How to subset a multidimensional numpy array with steps?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

I have a multi-dimensional array that is:

```
d.shape = (744, 1, 288, 315)
```

The first dimension is hours -- so I want to subset this array such that I only get the daytime hours, so hours 10-17 through each time 24-hour period.

I have been subsetting by creating a list:

```
start = 10
end = 17
d_daily = np.array([d[i*24+start:i*24+end] for i in range(31)])
```

but it's slow.

I feel like there should be a quick way for me to do a subset, something like:

```
d[start:(len(d)-(24-end)):24] # basically, take these 7 steps over and over until the end of the array
```

However, this gives me an array that is (31, 1, 288, 315) as opposed to the (217,1,288,315) output I would expect.

It is important that I keep the order of the data as well...

I know this is very simple, but I would appreciate your help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about this, using modular arithmetic:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((744, 1, 288, 315))

start = 10
end = 17

idx = np.arange(744) % 24
bool_arr = np.logical_and(idx >= 10, idx < 17)

d_daily = arr[bool_arr, :, :, :]
```

I'm using an array of zeros as an example, and this will include the hours from [10, 17) (i.e. 17 excluded).

Comment: Thank you! This does work, however it runs into the same problem I had before, in that it takes more time than necessary. The answer below, with the additional colons, was what I was looking for.

Comment: The other answer is just giving you all elements from 310 to 526 in the first dimension. i.e. from day 12.91 to day 21.95. I had understood you were after hours 10 to 17 from each day?

Answer (score 1):

Seems fairly simple as you told, can you try this?

```py
d[10*31:17*31,:,:,:]
```

Comment: Thank you! These colons were exactly what were required to make the formula work!

Comment: You are welcome! To be frank, you do not need those colons as well. Try it yourself once. I added them here for readability.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Isn't this simply taking the elements from 310 to 527?

Comment: Along axis=0 from 310 to 527 and all the rest of the elements along the other axes complying with the axis=0 slice